# plenty free inodes yet cannot write to disk

Tags: filesystem

I have a 1TB ext4 SSD mounted as data drive on ubuntu server 12.04. I use it to store files and noticed that @55% use I cannot add any new files/folders (get 'no space left on device' error message). One possibility is that there are no free inodes but then tune2fs shows that that there are still 58613749 free inodes (out of 58613760). There are at least few million files installed on this drive and I don't understand why there have not taken appropriate amount inodes. Is it possible for these stats to be inaccurate? If they are accurate not sure how) what else could cause the full disk behavior besides inodes?

Any insights and ideas are appreciated.

tune2fs output:

```
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              58613760
Block count:              234422870
Reserved block count:     11721143
Free blocks:              230692951
Free inodes:              58613749
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      968
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Mar 24 00:21:23 2014
Last mount time:          Mon Mar 24 00:26:29 2014
Last write time:          Mon Mar 24 00:26:29 2014
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Mar 24 00:21:23 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          134 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      73ef2ab5-f6d4-4515-8abd-2fe94905901b
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

df -i output:

```
Filesystem                Inodes    IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1               58613760 58613760       0  100% /media/data
```

Comment: What commands generate the error?  Can you `touch` an empty file?

Comment: tune2fs says `58613749` are free out of `58613760` ? Thats pretty huge for 55% use (Only 11 inodes used). Could you please share the output of `df -i`?

Comment: @belacqua - Creating a new file or folder generates the error. If I do it through windows (folder share with samba), I get 0 bytes free. If I do it in linux (ubuntu), no space left on device error is returned. I'll post the full stack above

Comment: @Nehal J. Wani. I can see the diff b/w tune2fs and df outputs when it comes to inode counts. This would indicate that tune2fs returns wrong stats from an ssd? I did a count of all files and subfolders on this drive and the total comes to 58,613,748.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `tune2fs -l` will show up to date information on your filesystem while it is mounted. `tune2fs` reads the filesystem directly from the disk, while the filesystem state is kept in memory while it is mounted. The superblock may not be written back to the disk at any point in time except when the filesystem is unmounted.

To get accurate block and inode usage counts on mounted filesystems, it is better to always use `df` and `df -i`.